# Bash Random Variables = Not so random?

Tags: bash, variables, random

I wanted to generate a random decimal that was rounded to the 10ths place between .1 and 1.

I did this with the command

```
`echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l`
```

Now if you set it as a variable, say

```
var=`echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l`
```

and have your script echo var like so,

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l`
echo $var
echo $var
echo $var
```

It repeats the same decimal, say .4, but if you

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l`
echo `echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l`
echo `echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l`
```

It will give you three random numbers using the same command as

```
$var=`echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l`
```

Why does Bash not generate three new numbers if given the same command but as a variable?

Comment: Re your last example -- `var=foo`, not `$var=foo`.

Comment: Actually $var=/=foo because it was defined at the top of the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command sets a value for `var`:

```
var=`echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l`
```

Once the value is set, it does not change.  Thus, however many times you view it, it will be the same:

```
echo $var
echo $var
echo $var
```

The only way to get a new value is for bash to evaluate `RANDOM` again.

#### Using a function instead

You might prefer a function that would return a different random variable with each invocation:

```
$ var() { echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l; }
$ var
.3
$ var
.4
$ var
1.0
$ var
.4
```

Comment: I see. I knew bash stored variables, but wasn't sure why it wouldn't execute the command on each new line! Thanks for the one-liner function idea. :)

Comment: Is there any way of adding functions? I have                                    #!/bin/bash
var() { echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l; }
add=$((`var`+`var`+`var`+`var`+ `var`))
echo $add             but I'm getting an operand error. Same thing with quotations around var.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, When I make my scripts I set it to #!/bin/bash and run with ./scriptname. My default interpreter is also bash not sh.

Comment: Oh. It's floating-point. Bash doesn't support floating-point math natively.

Comment: See BashFAQ #22: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022; this is why you're using `bc` rather than `$(( ))` alone in the first place.

Comment: Hence my problem with making it support floating point haha. Appears that it doesn't like adding fractions either. What a shame.

Comment: Use Korn shell, which *does* support floats?

Answer (score 2):

It is because

```
var=`echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l`
```

executes the echo command and **stores its output** into a variable. The command itself is only evaluated once by the bash interpreter.

If you want a compact way to generate a random number, I suggest using a *function*:

```
#!/bin/bash
myRandom(){
    echo "scale=1; $(( ( RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ))/10" | bc -l
}

echo $(myRandom)
echo $(myRandom)
echo $(myRandom)
```

Comment: Using backticks?  Not `echo $(myRandom)`?

Comment: @cdarke Both are possible. AFAIK, the `$()`-syntax was adopted later for readability (from Korn shell).

Comment: If by later you mean about 20 years ago, then yes, but the backtick form is considered obsolete in bash and if you use ksh -n then it is flagged as deprecated.  See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst